# Как исправить перескакивание фокуса с одного EditText на другое в ListView? Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

В ListView есть элементы, которые содержат несколько компонентов EditText. При тапе на один из компонентов, открывается клавиатура, но фокус перескакивает на другой EditText. Как исправить?

Comment: Странно. Само собой не должно пререскакивать. Может код покажите?

Comment: @PawelShi [Cсылка на адаптер](https://github.com/JamyCake/Smart_Shopping_List/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jamycake/smartshoppinglist/view/android/adapter/BasketToListViewAdapter.java) Не знаю, где именно может крыться ошибка, но думаю, что в адаптере.

Comment: На первый взгляд не нашел, что модет вызвать такое поведение фокуса. Можно  взять проект, чтобы попробовать вживую? Мне нравится ваш код, очень чистый и доступный.

Comment: @PawelShi Да, берите. Только оставьте замечания по поводу кода и, возможно, предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем, как вызвать из адаптера view, содержащий EditText, надо у всех EditText`ов очистить фокусы, так как адаптер создаёт представления только 1 раз